How to prevent the AI opponent from forfeiting?
I'm playing skirmish mode against AI. The victory condition is set to standard. Every time I start to get the upper hand, I get a message saying that I've won. It seems like the AI resigns. I remember in the original version, you had to find and kill the last soldier and destroy the last building before winning. Sometimes it was frustrating to hunt them down, but the feeling of victory was much better when I crushed the enemy completely.
How can I set the victory conditions to be similar to those in the original version?
I've tried a lot already, and even when I set the mode to King of the Hill, the game didn't wait until I killed the opponent's king; the AI surrendered as soon as I gained some advantage.

You can choose to play against the CD, HD, or DE AIs by default, or can download more off the mod workshop (Promi, Rehoboam, etc). You may find more luck with the CD AI, though even it has been tweaked over time (as it must be, considering the extra civilizations and changed game mechanics). While one can certainly 104 the AI to prevent a resignation, it generally won't occur when you only begin to have the "upper hand". The AI is designed to resign when, assuming reasonable play, there is no chance left for it to win. This is the same as any multiplayer, where resignation is expected.

From the Devs directly on their forum:

If you open the large chat window in-game and select the enemy AIs as
eligible to receive your chats then you can send them the AI command
#104 (either from the list or by sending “104” as a message) to prohibit them from resigning.


What a perfectly cromulent way to access this setting.

If you're in a 1v1 against an AI, you can simply hit Enter (or whatever your "chat" hotkey is), type 104, and hit Enter again. No need to mess with chat settings when there's only one other player. (You can also do this with human opponents, but your results may vary.)

of note, there is a little gap between them deciding to resign and actually resigning, typically can be inferred by deleting their own granaries at times for some reason.. in that little gap 104 won't work
